# MariaDB CHECK constraint in VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, mariadb, check-constraints

I am not sure what is wrong below:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_bookmarks` ADD CONSTRAINT id_length CHECK (LENGTH(bookmark_id) = 36);
```

Purpose: I want a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) data in my primary key - bookmark_id.
The SQL above runs successfully, and the constraint is not added in the database.

The SHOW CREATE TABLE does not show the constraint in the body. Also, the query above runs multiple times (I expected error on second attempt as the index name is repeated). My database is MariaDB 10.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you use MariaDB with version lower than 10.2.1. You could easily check it with:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

From [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/):

> From MariaDB 10.2.1, constraints are enforced. **Before MariaDB 10.2.1 constraint expressions were accepted in the syntax but ignored.**

I suggest to upgrade your DB to newer version.

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fa4ed9a38c52c74a073d624f966f4db0)**

Comment: Thank you for pointing it. It may be so. My version appears to be a bit older.